# C# Tenho um bot de troca da Steam e ele retorna o erro "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto"

Tags: c#

Eu procurei em todos os outros tópicos e vi várias respostas mas não consigo aplicá-las na minha aplicação por não saber nada de C#...
Meu site é de apostas do CS:GO e eu tenho um bot em C# que funciona normalmente como deveria(quando completa a quantidade de items no pot de apostas ele faz o sorteio) mas preciso que ele também ative quando acabar o tempo para deposito de skins.
Então eu simplesmente peguei o comando que ele executa quando o pot fica cheio e colei na parte em que o tempo acaba.

O comando que funciona(partes dele) é esse:

```
namespace SteamBot
{
public class DepositTradeOfferUserHandler : UserHandler
{
    public DepositTradeOfferUserHandler(bot bot, SteamID sid) : base(bot,       sid) { }
...
...
...
BotInventory botInventory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BotInventory> (botInvString);
                    if (botInventory.success != true) {
                        Log.Error ("An error occured while fetching the bot's inventory.");
                        return;
                    }
                    var rgInventory = botInventory.rgInventory;

                    //Create trade offer for the winner
                    var winnerTradeOffer = Bot.NewTradeOffer (winnerSteamID);
```

Essa parte funciona perfeitamente... Agora a parte que eu criei que é ativada quando o tempo acaba e o sorteio é realizado:

```
Task f = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {

        int count = 1;


        while (count <= 1)
        {
...
...
...
var rgInventory = botInventory.rgInventory;

                //Create trade offer for the winner
                var winnerTradeOffer = bot.NewTradeOffer(winnerSteamID);

                //Loop through all winner's items and add them to trade
                List<long> alreadyAddedToWinnerTrade = new List<long>();
```

Reparem que é o mesmo comando mas nesse segundo bloco o código não funciona.
Mensagem de erro: `CS0120  C# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'bot.NewTradeOffer(SteamID)'`

Eu sei que deve ser algo simples, mas eu não entendo nada de C# e preciso muito da ajuda de vocês, obrigado.
Se precisarem de mais algum código ou explicação é só falar.
Obrigado desde já!

EDIT: Eu reparei que os dois códigos não estavam similares então renomeei "bot" para "Bot" para assim ficar igual, e agora a mensagem de erro é essa: `CS0236  C# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'UserHandler.Bot'`

Comment: Esse erro está dando nessa linha var winnerTradeOffer = bot.NewTradeOffer(winnerSteamID); da parte que vc copiou e colou?

Comment: Tem razão que tem diferença entre `bot` e `Bot`-- provavelmente, um é uma instância do classe `Bot`, e o outro é a classe `Bot` em se. A função `NewTradeOffer()` é `static`? Se for, `Bot.NewTradeOffer` está certo.